# onCall cloud function returns 'Data cannot be encoded in JSON. NAN'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an onCall function that looks like this..

```
exports.getResults = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const admin = context.auth.token.admin
  const uniqueId = context.auth.uid
  const doc = db.collection('collection').doc(data.docId)

    return doc
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          const doc = doc.data()
          const collectionDoc = {
            docValues
          }
    
          return collectionDoc
        })
      })
```

my console.log prints the doc I am requesting as an object, so I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: What *exactly* are you expecting this function to return other than an error?  What is the log printing?  Please edit the question to explain what is not working the way you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand that you have this error in Firebase Function logs. This means that you are returning `NaN` somewhere in the object. According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result) article:

> To send data back to the client, return data that can be JSON encoded.

It may depend on implementation, however here `NaN` is cannot be JSON encoded. (Found something about it in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) - Data types and syntax - Number).

You can easily replicate this problem by deploying function with not initialized variable:

```
exports.getResults = functions.https.onCall(() => {
        var number;
        var value = number+1;
        return {
                value,
                "text": "test",
        };
})
```

In the example I added `undefined` to number the result will be `NaN`. Of course there might be other functions that will return `NaN` as well. Anyway if you deploy example above, it will log the same error "Data cannot be encoded in JSON. NaN". I think this is most easily to be overlooked in the code.

I think you have to carefully check all data that you are returning.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it following your steps. Cheers for the detailed post, really appreciate it